# How to display a vector of elements on a list view?

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview, qtwidgets

I have two functions `getProjects()` and `getEmployees()`, in a class called `manage` from `manage.h`, that basically return a vector with all the projects/employees I've added until now.

How can I display it in my Qt application interface?

I've created two buttons (in a `stackedWidget`), one to get all the projects when clicked and the other one for the employees, and I've also used a `QListView` that should show all my data when I click one of the two buttons, but how do I tell the QListView to display my vector's elements?

I think the solution would look like something like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_showAllProjects_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->listView->something(manage.getProjects());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need a QStringList to put the elements of your vector into, then a QStringListModel, which you need to set its stringlist to your stringlist, then set this QStringListModel as your listview model, and that does what you need.

Here's an example:

```
QStringListModel *model = new QStringListModel(this);

QStringList List;
List << "Project1" << "Project2" << "Project3";

model->setStringList(List);
ui->listView->setModel(model);
```

If you don't have to use the model based list, you can use QListWidget instead, it provides a method `addItem()`, which is very straightforward compared to QListView.

For more: [Qt5 Tutorial ModelView with QListView and QStringListModel](https://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QListView_QStringListModel_ModelView_MVC.php).